# A question on the possibility of a continuous surjective function from $(a,b) \mapsto [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, contest-math, solution-verification

$\mathbf{Original \ Question}: $  Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

(A) There exists a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to (a,b)$ such that $f$ is one-one

(B) There exists a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to (a,b)$ such that $f$ is onto

(C) There exists a continuous function $f:(a,b) \to [a,b]$ such that $f$ is one-one

(D) There exists a continuous function $f:(a,b) \to [a,b]$ such that $f$ is onto

$\mathbf{Attempt}:$

Option $A$ is true. For example, consider $a=0 ,b=1$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2(x+1)}$.

Option $C$ is true. $f(x)=x$  with $a=0,b=1$.

Option $B$ cannot be true, Since: $f^{-1}((a,b))=[a,b]$ and by the property of continuous functions, $f^{-1}((a,b))$ must be an open set. But $[a,b]$ is closed.

Option $D$ cannot be true since $f^{-1}([a,b])=(a,b)$ must be a closed set. But $(a,b)$ is open.

But, in the answer key, $D$ is given as a correct choice. What am I doing wrong here?

Any insight is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What about $f(x)=\dfrac{a+b}2+\dfrac{b-a}2\sin\left(\dfrac{(x-a)}{(b-a)}2\pi\right)$?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that the function is defined on $(a,b)$ only, and on $(a,b)$, in the subspace topology, the set $(a,b)$ is "the whole space" so it is both open and closed. That renders your argument for $D$ incorrect, but also for $B$. (I believe for $B$ you can use that direct image of a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ must be compact.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop I get it now. We have to regard the the intervals as the subspaces of $(\mathbb{R},d)$. $X$ is clopen in $(X,d)$. So, $[a,b]$ in itself becomes open. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you!

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas Here's another example for D with $a=0,b=1$:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & 0<x\leq1/3\\
3x-1 & 1/3\leq x\leq 2/3 \\
1 & 2/3\leq x < 1

\end{cases} $$

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas: Since the comments of JW Tanner and Stinking Bishop effectively answered your question, but they didn't make an actual answer, I suggest you answer your own question with what you learned from their comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP hasn't tried to fully answer this question after rectifying the shortfalls in his attempt, here's a short answer:

(A) There exists a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to (a,b)$ such that $f$ is one-one.

**Sol.** True.  Take $f(x)= y$ satisfying $\dfrac {y-(a + \frac{a-b}{4})}{x-a}=\dfrac{1}{4}$

(B) There exists a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to (a,b)$ such that $f$ is onto

**Sol.**  False. Since, $[a,b]$ is compact and connected, $f([a,b])$ must be compact and an interval since $f$ is required to be onto. Thus, $f([a,b])$ must be a closed interval, but then $f$ cannot map onto $(a,b)$.

(C) There exists a continuous function $f:(a,b) \to [a,b]$ such that $f$ is one-one

**Sol.** True. Take $f(x)=x$

(D) There exists a continuous function $f:(a,b) \to [a,b]$ such that $f$ is onto

**Sol.** The solution to $D$ can be constructed in the following manner

[image]

Comment: Comments are not as permanent as answers. It would be good to quote an example for part D.